# Angular 2 get router params in modal window

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

i'm try to get route params in my modal window component to use them in REST service with following code

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.params
```

but got error - Cannot read property 'params' of null

i'm logging this.activatedRoute , url === ''

perhaps someone already faced with problem like this and will be able to tell how to get the URL in a modal window?

thanks in advance

Comment: or maybe the right solution - simply transfer URL from the parent component?

Comment: This question is easily solved through the service, but I really want to find `angular` way solution

Comment: can you post some code of how you're presenting the modal, perhaps an example plunkr

Comment: i'm use custom modal service, with angular ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef

Comment: cant edit prev comment --->

i'm use custom modal service, with angular ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, ComponentRef

find solution here - https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/RouterStateSnapshot-interface.html

or another solution - simply send data to modal service on open modal event, if your service supprot this - actually I did

unfortunately, as a modal window is separately routed through activatedRoute is not possible to get url, it's hidden property

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm find solution with **RouterStateSnapshot** [here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/RouterStateSnapshot-interface.html)

Another way - actually i did - send URL to modal service on open modal event, if your service support this

```
openModal() {
    this.modalService.open(CreateModalComponent, { id: this.id });
  }
```

to get the static id from observable in parent component

```
.do(id => { this.id = id; });
```

Comment: .do to what? and the link does not work. another thing is that the other parameter of function open is of NgbModalOptions type, and you can't add other attributes to it.